# Can I use activerecord-nulldb-adapter in JRuby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I use **activerecord-nulldb-adapter** in Ruby to test the case which using active record because I don't want to connect to DB.

But in **JRuby**, I don't know well Can I use activerecord-nulldb-adapter or not?

If can't use, Is there anything can I use instead of activerecord-nulldb-adapter in JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `activerecord-nulldb-adapter` because it is implemented in pure Ruby and therefore will run under JRuby: https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb

Comment: How can I test the gem(that I implemented only using ruby) in JRuby. I also don't know well how to test in JRuby.

Comment: Follow the instructions on the link I provided.